AppleTV type: A1625 not able to play H265 with Fairplay DRM stream(DRM is Verimatrix)
When A1625 play H265 DRM stream, directly show below error:
Same stream can play in A1842 and IOS version is the same.
enter image description here
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-SESSION-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="skd://4aa4aaf0fdf8b234a456b8c663572a23",KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="mp4a.40.2",LANGUAGE="ara",NAME="ara",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO,CHANNELS="2",URI="audio_ara_mp4a.40_2000-PolicyMode_2_hls6_6_fp_vmxmultidrm_ott_ooredoo_saes_iso.m3u8?jitxpolicy=PolicyMode_Content_fmp4_CA_6s&pbf=1_2_4_3056475013"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4213577,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L120.B0,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="mp4a.40.2"
1-PolicyMode_2_hls6_6_fp_vmxmultidrm_ott_ooredoo_saes_iso.m3u8?jitxpolicy=PolicyMode_Content_fmp4_CA_6s&pbf=1_2_4_3056475013
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1646588,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L93.B0,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="mp4a.40.2"
2-PolicyMode_2_hls6_6_fp_vmxmultidrm_ott_ooredoo_saes_iso.m3u8?jitxpolicy=PolicyMode_Content_fmp4_CA_6s&pbf=1_2_4_3056475013
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=883304,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L90.B0,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480,AUDIO="mp4a.40.2"
3-PolicyMode_2_hls6_6_fp_vmxmultidrm_ott_ooredoo_saes_iso.m3u8?jitxpolicy=PolicyMode_Content_fmp4_CA_6s&pbf=1_2_4_3056475013
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=529542,CODECS="hev1.1.6.L63.B0,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="mp4a.40.2"
4-PolicyMode_2_hls6_6_fp_vmxmultidrm_ott_ooredoo_saes_iso.m3u8?jitxpolicy=PolicyMode_Content_fmp4_CA_6s&pbf=1_2_4_3056475013
Attach the A1625 debug logs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wuCr9JsL9RFm7f3INpraWsInqdXaEVMq/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115694401825562093408&rtpof=true&sd=true
Attach the Manifest:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4ofnrDUD1p1vCFTVRLnbso4Bpad2ML9/view?usp=sharing
attach the A1625 device info:
enter image description here
